# Does Abyssal Mask work with Immobilizing coming from items?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing Garen on ARAM and bought a Stridebreaker. Stridebreaker slows enemies. If I also had Abyssal mask would that procc its effect or is it limited to Immobilizing with champion abilities?

> Immobilizing enemy champions increases the damage they take by 10% for 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your specific situation (Garen with Stridebreaker and Abyssal Mask) there are two questions that need to be answered.

**Does Abyssal Mask's *Unmake* passive trigger off of immobilizing effects from items?**

Yes. To test this, I jumped into the practice tool as Garen, spawned an enemy target dummy, and bought both [Everfrost](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Everfrost) and [Abyssal Mask](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Abyssal_Mask). When rooting the enemy dummy with the centre of Everfrost's active it also received a debuff from Abyssal Mask which reads "This unit takes amplified damage".

[image]

**Does a slow count as an immobilizing effect?**

No. To test this, I simply hit the enemy target dummy with the edge of Everfrost's active effect rather than the centre, which slows instead of roots. In this situation, there was no debuff from Abyssal Mask.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, Abysal Mask works only with "hard CCs", because "Slow" is soft cc, but still marked as "Immobilizing effect": https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Crowd_control#Immobilization

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Yes, only the things listed as a "hard CC" in that table are actually considered immobilizing effects. I don't know who decided including a table splitting status effects into hard vs soft CC was helpful in that section of the page. If you hover your cursor over the word "immobilizing" on the Abyssal Mask page it provides a clearer/more useful list of what actually counts.